# Nodejs/Express - subdomain automatically redirects to root domain

Tags: node.js, express

Hey I created a small registration script with email confirmation and I wanted to use express-subdomain here. Everything works fine except for the confirmation part. If I click the link in the confirmation email, it redirects me to the confirmation subdomain ( http://login.myapp.com:5000/reg/confirm?id=xxx )... and here is the problem. The server should receive the get request with the Id and update the database:

```
loginapp.get('/reg/confirm', function (req, res) {
  var unid = req.query.id;
  console.log('before update');
  db.confirmAccount(unid, function (error, unid) {
   if (error) throw error;
   console.log('after update');
   res.redirect('http://myapp.com:5000');
  });
})
```

but instead it just automatically redirects me to http://myapp.com:5000 without even going into that code (No outputs in console and db wont get updated).

Subdomain configuration:

```
const express = require('express');
const subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
var app = express();
var loginapp = express.Router();

app.use(subdomain('login', loginapp));
app.listen(5000, function () {
 console.log('+++ LISTENING ON PORT 5000 +++');
});
```

Is there a problem with my code or is it because of express-subdomain?

Comment: There's something wrong with this `else` hanging without `if` in its scope. Are you sure this is syntactically valid?

Comment: Oh that's true, fixed it but still the same result. like I said it doesn't even run the code if I open the site...

Comment: Could you fix the snippet included in the question then?

Comment: um well I already did

Comment: Check once your router with get or post method as you mentioned here get.

Comment: This seems to be a configuration problem of your web server (and not the code you provided here). Otherwise it should at least output `before update` on the console. Can you provide more about how you configured the subdomain on the web server?

Comment: @SebastianHildebrandt Sure, I updated the question. Maybe it's worth to know that when I open http://login.myapp.com:5000 it just works as expected and doesn't redirect at all

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and made a little test. I had to modify my `/etc/hosts` (Windows: `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) like this by adding:

```
127.0.0.1   myapp.com
127.0.0.1   login.myapp.com
```

Your code (here I moved it all in one file):

```
const express = require('express');
const subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
var app = express();
var loginapp = express.Router();

loginapp.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Login is working');
  console.log('LOGIN');
})

loginapp.get('/reg/confirm', function (req, res) {
  var unid = req.query.id;
  console.log('before update');
  console.log(unid);

  db.confirmAccount(unid, function (error, unid) {
   if (error) throw error;
   console.log('after update');
   res.redirect('http://myapp.com:5000');
  });
})

app.use(subdomain('login', loginapp));

app.listen(5000, function () {
 console.log('+++ LISTENING ON PORT 5000 +++');
});
```

This works pretty fine (of course I am getting a DB error but I can see it tackles the correct route)! So I guess, it is not really a problem in the code itself ...

Comment: Hm, thank you for testing it on your side! But I would still like to know where this problem comes from... if its not the code itself, what could it be instead?

Comment: Can you try the above code on your side. Then we could at least see if this works or if it is something outside the provided code.

Comment: Ok, I tried it several times and logged everything in the console and it looks like its working so far...

Comment: Oh wow looks like I solved it... just changed the path from `/reg/confirm`to `/reg/con`and now it works...

Answer (score 0):

I just renamed the path for the get request from:

```
loginapp.get('/reg/confirm', function (req, res) {
 var unid = req.query.id;
 console.log('before update');
 console.log(unid);

 db.confirmAccount(unid, function (error, unid) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('after update');
  res.redirect('http://myapp.com:5000');
 });
})
```

to

```
loginapp.get('/reg/con', function (req, res) {
 var unid = req.query.id;
 console.log('before update');
 console.log(unid);

 db.confirmAccount(unid, function (error, unid) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('after update');
  res.redirect('http://myapp.com:5000');
 });
})
```

and now everything works fine...

Comment: And explanation for that?

Comment: Hm no idea, I'm sorry... If I'll find out what the problem was I will add it!